# Cart increment and decrement values JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to increment and decrement values in a cart. I first implemented it by targeting an id, and my js code worked. But then I realized that I'll have mulitple items in the cart so I won't be able to target the IDs, so then I changed from getElementById to getElementsByClassName, but the js code no longer works. How can I solve this?

```
<div class="quantity">
 <form>
   <div class="value-button" class="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
     <input type="number" class="number" value="1" />
   <div class="value-button" class="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value">+</div>
 </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
// Increase Value // 
function increaseValue() {
      var value = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName('number').value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 1 : value;
      value++;
      document.getElementsByClassName('number').value = value;
}
    
// Decrease Value // 
function decreaseValue() {
      var value = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName('number').value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
      value--;
      document.getElementsByClassName('number').value = value;
}
```

My Previous code that was working

```
<div class="quantity">
  <form>
   <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
     <input type="number" id="number" value="1" />
   <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value">+</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
// Increase Value // 
function increaseValue() {
      var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value++;
      document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
    
// Decrease Value // 
function decreaseValue() {
      var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
      value--;
      document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`; you need to iterate over that and set the value on each contained element individually rather than trying to set the value of the `HTMLCollection` itself.

Or just use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), like this:

```js
// Increase Value // 
function increaseValue() {
      var value = parseInt(document.querySelector('.number').value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 1 : value;
      value++;
      document.querySelector('.number').value = value;
}
    
// Decrease Value // 
function decreaseValue() {
      var value = parseInt(document.querySelector('.number').value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
      value--;
      document.querySelector('.number').value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName return collection.

Instead `document.getElementsByClassName('number').value` you need use `document.getElementsByClassName('number')[0].value`

Comment: Won't you need a loop to go along with this to loop through each element? Or can this work as it is?

Comment: I write it for your example of code. If you have some elements with class 'number' you need know correct index.

Comment: How do I go about knowing the correct index for each class, and then change those index individually based on which specific item quantity is modified?

Comment: See my other answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onclick in html use addEventListener.
For example you have some quantity.

```
<div class="quantity">
 <form>
   <div class="value-button" class="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
     <input type="number" class="number" value="1" />
   <div class="value-button" class="increase" value="Increase Value">+</div>
 </form>
</div>
<div class="quantity">
 <form>
   <div class="value-button" class="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
     <input type="number" class="number" value="1" />
   <div class="value-button" class="increase" value="Increase Value">+</div>
 </form>
</div>
<div class="quantity">
 <form>
   <div class="value-button" class="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
     <input type="number" class="number" value="1" />
   <div class="value-button" class="increase" value="Increase Value">+</div>
 </form>
</div>

let quantities = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity');
for (let i=0; i<quantities.length; i++) {
    let q = quantities[i];
    let increaseElement = q.getElementsByClassName('increase')[0];
    increaseElement.addEventListener('click', increaseValue, false);

    function increaseValue() {
      var value = parseInt(q.getElementsByClassName('number')[0].value, 10);
      value++;
      q.getElementsByClassName('number')[0].value = value;
    }
}
```